# How can i take an array, divide it by two and create two lists?

Tags: php, arrays

Say i have an array

```
$array
```

Could anyone give me an example of how to use a foreach loop and print two lists after the initial array total has been counted and divided by two, with any remainder left in the second list?

So instead of just using the foreach to create one long list it will be creating two lists? like so...

1. Value 1
2. Value 2
3. Value 3

and then the second list will continue to print in order

1. Value 4
2. Value 5
3. Value 6

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To get a part of an array, you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$len = (int) count($input);

$firsthalf = array_slice($input, 0, $len / 2);
$secondhalf = array_slice($input, $len / 2);
```

Comment: Original poster wanted the extra element in the second half, but if you want the extra element in the first half, use round($len / 2) in both places where you have $len / 2.

Comment: @DustinGraham how about `floor()` in the first half and `ceil()` in the second? An array with 5 items will be split as following: 2 / 3

Comment: @Fleuv: An array with 5 items under your scenario would be split 1,2 and 4,5.  The middle item would be left out.  Coincidentally, that was just what I wanted, so thanks!

Comment: To ignore middle element, use `round($len/2)` in second half only.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the array up into multiple sub-arrays, and then loop over each.

To find out how large the chunks should be to divide the array in half, use `ceil(count($array) / 2)`.

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$arrays = array_chunk($input_array, 3);

foreach ($arrays as $array_num => $array) {
  echo "Array $array_num:\n";
  foreach ($array as $item_num => $item) {
    echo "  Item $item_num: $item\n";
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array 0:
  Item 0: a
  Item 1: b
  Item 2: c
Array 1:
  Item 0: d
  Item 1: e
  Item 2: f
```

Comment: Thanks for putting it in a foreach e.t.c although most guys are suggesting array_slice..

Answer (score 14):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

To slice the array into half, use floor(count($array)/2) to know your offset.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a one-liner which uses array_chunk:

```
list($part1, $part2) = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / 2));
```

If you need to preserve keys, add true as the third argument:

```
list($part1, $part2) = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / 2), true);
```

Comment: Hi @James Thank you for the solution, I came up with your solution and it's working fine but sometimes I'm getting `Warning: array_chunk(): Size parameter expected to be greater than 0 ` my code line is `list($array1, $array2) = array_chunk($myarray, ceil(count($myarray) / 2));` the code works fine and sometimes it will just throw that error, can you please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi @ZackTim sorry this answer is a long time later, so presumably it's no longer relevant. I assume that what's happening is that the array is empty? If so, you would need to do some kind of check to count that it has at least two elements in the array before it reaches this code, and handle it appropriately, e.g. setting $part1 = []; $part2 = [];

Comment: you have to cast it to int: `list($part1, $part2) = array_chunk($array, (int) ceil(count($array) / 2));`

Answer (score 2):

```
$limit=count($array);

$first_limit=$limit/2;
for($i=0;$i<$first; $i++)
{
  echo $array[$i];
}
foreach ($i=$first; $i< $limit; $i++)
{
  echo $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a foreach loop you could do this:

```
$myarray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
$i = 1;

foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    if ($i <= count($myarray) / 2) {
        $array1[] = $value;
    } else {
        $array2[] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But it's even easier to use array_splice

```
$myarray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
$array1 = array_splice($myarray, 0, floor(count($myarray)/2));
$array2 = $myarray;
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_splice()` is a single native function call which will perform as needed.  It can:

1. Mutate the original array to contain the first half of the data set and
2. Return the *removed* second half of the data set.

The advantage in using this technique is that fewer functions are called and fewer variable are declared.  In other words, there will be economy in terms of memory and performance.

Assuming you don't know the length of your array, `count() divided by 2` will be necessary.  For scenarios where the array count is odd, typically programmers prefer that the larger half comes first.  To ensure this, use a negative value as the starting position parameter of the splice call.  Because the native function expects an integer (not a float), it will automatically truncate the value to form an integer -- this replaces the need to call an extra function (such as `ceil()` or `floor()`).  In my snippet to follow, the count is 5, half is 2.5, and the negative truncated starting position is 2 -- this means the final two elements will be removed from the input array.

A [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/fb0Cn):

```
$array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

$removed = array_splice(
    $array,
    -count($array) / 2
);

var_export([
    'first half' => $array,
    'second half' => $removed
]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'first half' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '3',
  ),
  'second half' => 
  array (
    0 => '4',
    1 => '5',
  ),
)
```

Notice that the second half array is conveniently re-indexed.

`array_chunk()` is certainly appropriate as well and offers some conveniences.  To avoid the extra `ceil()` call, just unconditionally add `.5` to the preferred chunk length.

```
array_chunk($array, count($array) / 2 + .5)
```

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me made the first array always a little longer. Thought this might help people too.

```
$firsthalf = array_slice($input, 0, $len / 2 +1);
$secondhalf = array_slice($input, $len / 2 +1);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use laravel helper function.

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
$collections = collect($input);
$chuncks = $collections->chuck(3) 
$chuncks->toArray(); // [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e", "f"]]
```

souce:[Array into chunks and results by chunks in a new line with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315876/array-into-chunks-and-results-by-chunks-in-a-new-line-with-php)