# Splitting array content to different divs in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a dynamic navigation menu.
All allowed possibilities are defined in an array.
I'm trying to count the array, split it in half and print each half of the array into seperate div's. One on the left side of the screen and the other on the right side.

this is what i've got:

```
function menu_main() {                                                                          

    $count = count($GLOBALS['menu']);
    $count = round($count / 2);

    $menu_1 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], 0, $count);
    $menu_2 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], $count++);

    echo '  <div id="menu_1">' . "\n";
        foreach($menu_1 as $page) {

            echo '  <div class="menu_items">' . "\n";
            echo '  <a class="menu" href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> .' . "\n";    //Create menu left
            echo '  </div>'. "\n";  


        }   
    echo '  </div>'. "\n";

    echo '  <div id="menu_2">' . "\n";
        foreach($menu_2 as $page) {

            echo '  <div class="menu_items">' . "\n";
            echo '  <a class="menu" href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> .' . "\n";    //Create menu right
            echo '  </div>'. "\n";  


        }   
    echo '  </div>'. "\n";

}
```

Is there a way to do this with itteration?
This works but it looks way to messy.

Comment: Please google, search or something before posting already asked question. Here's what I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393028/how-can-i-take-an-array-divide-it-by-two-and-create-two-lists

Comment: Make another function to use redundant code.

Comment: if it works and you only want to improve readability and design i can advise to post your question at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a couple of things:

```
$GLOBALS['menu'];
```

Why use `$GLOBALS`, or `global $menu`, for that matter? Why not ***pass what you need to the function***?

```
function menuMain(array $menu)
{
    $count = floor(count($menu)/2);
```

Would make a lot more sense. Also:

```
$menu_1 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], 0, $count);
$menu_2 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], $count++);//<== why the increment?
```

Why are you incrementing `$count`, only to then not use it anymore? You're post-incrementing the value, which means that if `$count` is 10, then the code above is evaluated to:

```
$menu_1 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], 0, 10);
$menu_2 = array_slice($GLOBALS['menu'], 10);//10+1 happens AFTER the array_slice call is made
```

Also don't use `"\n"`, because line-feeds are system dependent, PHP has a predefine constant for this reason: `PHP_EOL`. Use it (that's an order).
And don't concatenate what you `echo`, just comma-separate it:

```
echo 'foo', 'bar', PHP_EOL;
echo 'foo'.'bar'.PHP_EOL;
```

both may produce the same time, but the first version is faster, because the strings are pushed to the output, without first concatenating them into a new string.
Not that it matters here, because functions should *return* something, not echo it.

Anyway, your question: is there a way to do this with iteration? Yes, and you're already iterating (`foreach` iterates an array/object).
An alternative approach would be:

```
function mainMenu (array $menu)
{
    $return ='  <div id="menu_1">' . PHP_EOL;//functions shouldn't echo
    //start with div 1
    for($i = 0, $j= count($menu), $count = floor($j/2); $i<$j;++$i)
    {
        if ($i == $count)
        {//reached half-way marker, close div 1, open div 2
            $return .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL.'<div id="menu_2">'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        $return .= '  <div class="menu_items">' . PHP_EOL
               .'  <a class="menu" href="index.php?page=' . $menu[$i] . '">' . $menu[$i]
               . '</a> .' .PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $return.'</div>';//close div2 and return
}
```

That should give you the exact same output as before, only it only uses a single loop, doesn't rely on globals, and doesn't echo things, so you call it like this:

```
$menu = array('your', 'global', 'array');
echo mainMenu($menu);//pass the array, echo what it returns
```

Comment: I guess i need to be reading a bit more instead of trying to code already.
Been at it for two weeks now, clearly i'm not even close to understanding what i'm doing.

Thanks for the clear answer, really helped!

Comment: @RicoEightySix: you can't learn to program without writing code, and when learning to code, you're bound to be writing code that works, but you yourself don't understand, just as you will write code that you think should work, but it doesn't. It's all part of the learning process. In a couple of months, you'll be looking back at your early attempts and you'll want to deny ever having written them... we all have to go through that phase. There's no shame in it, whatever you write, however messy it looks, if you learned something in writing it, it was worth your while.

Comment: Fair enough! I was trying to memorize the things i had taught myself over 10 years ago and put that together to get this dynamic menu.
It's time to read and practice, planning on really learning this thing this time.

Anyway, i want to ask two things about your code.
I do understand the logic behind it and i can figure out how it works but there are two things i don't get:

- I am clueless on how the return with the $return variables works
- i have absolutely no idea why you use .=

can't seem to find anything that i'm capable of understanding about this.

Comment: @RicoEightySix: Well, the `$return` variable could've been called `$string`, too... it's just a variable to which I'm adding new bits of string. I'm building the output string as I go along. Instead of `echo`-ing the lot, I return a string. the `.=` operator is short for `$return = $return . ' new bit of string';` just like `$i += 1` is short for `$i = $i + 1`. The return statement: `return $return.'</div>';` just exploits the precedence the concatenation operator has of the `return` construct. I'm returning the value of `$return` + the closing `</div>` tag. That's all there's too it

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution if it helps.

```
$menu = array ("link1","link2","link3","link4","link5");

function menu_main() 
{                                                                          
    global $menu;
    $count = count($menu);
    $menu_items = round($count / 2);

    //initialize the divs for menus
    $output_menu[0] = '  <div id="menu_1">' . "\n";
    $output_menu[1] = '  <div id="menu_2">' . "\n";

    $menu_count = 0;
        foreach($menu as $link) 
        {
            if ($menu_count < $menu_items)
            {
                //what enters in first menu
                $output_menu[0] .= '  <div class="menu_items">' . "\n";
                $output_menu[0] .= '  <a class="menu" href="index.php?page=' . $link . '">' . ucfirst($link) . '</a> .' . "\n";    //Create menu left
                $output_menu[0] .= '  </div>'. "\n";  
            }
            else
            {
                //what enters in second menu
                $output_menu[1] .= '  <div class="menu_items">' . "\n";
                $output_menu[1] .= '  <a class="menu" href="index.php?page=' . $link . '">' . ucfirst($link) . '</a> .' . "\n";    //Create menu left
                $output_menu[1] .= '  </div>'. "\n";  
            }
            $menu_count++;

        }   

    //close the divs for menus
    $output_menu[0] .= '  </div>'. "\n";  
    $output_menu[1] .= '  </div>'. "\n";

    //return array with content for menus
    return $output_menu;

}

$menu_main = menu_main(); // get content in variable
print_r($menu_main[0]); //print 1st menu
print_r($menu_main[1]); //print 2nd menu
```

Comment: I will look into your code as well, thanks for your input.

What does the ".=" do? Can't find anything about it.
Still figuring out how that return $return; from the code above works as well.

Comment: $var .= "something is the same as $var = $var . "something"               Works for $var += -= *= aswell :)