# how to print half values of an array in a table column and half values in another column?

Tags: php

I have an array where I am merging the values of two arrays to create a new array. I want the half values of the array to be printed out in first cell of the column and the other half in the second column. How can I do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Result PHP Array I am having**

```
Array ( [0] => Test Task 1 
        [1] => Test Task 2 
        [2] => Test Task 3 
        [3] => Normal 
        [4] => Important 
        [5] => Urgent )
```

**Whole Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $tasks=$_POST['txttask'];
        $priority=$_POST['priority'];
        $final_array=array_merge($tasks,$priority);


        include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

        $mpdf=new mPDF(); 

        $html  = '<table width="100%">';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td width="50%"><h1>Logo</h1></td>';
        $html .= '<td width="50%" align="right"><h2>Work Order</h2></td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td><h3>Company Name</h3></td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td><address>Street Address </address></td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td><address>City St Zip Code</address></td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';        
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td><address>Phone:123 456 Fax:123 456</address></td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td width="100%" align="right">Job: A description just for testing.<td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '</table>';
        $html .= '<table border="1">';
        $html .= '<thead>';
        $html .= '<tr><th>Task</th><th>Prority</th><tr>';
        $html .= '</thead>';
        $html .= '<tbody>';
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($final_array)$i++){
            $t;
            $p;
            if($i%2!=0){
                $t=$final_array[$i];
            } else {
                $p=$final_array[$i];
            }
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>''<td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</tbody>';
        $html .= '</table>';

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        // $mpdf->Output();
        $mpdf->Output('MyPDF.pdf', 'D');
        exit;



    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i take an array, divide it by two and create two lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393028/how-can-i-take-an-array-divide-it-by-two-and-create-two-lists)

Comment: Although I think this is a duplicate, I also think Sougata's answer is cleaner than the accepted over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help -

```
$array = array( 'Test Task 1', 'Test Task 2', 'Test Task 3', 'Normal', 'Important', 'Urgent' );
$chunks= array_chunk($array, floor(count($array)/2)); // split array in 2 halves

echo '<table><tr>';
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
   echo '<td>' . implode(', ', $chunk) . '</td>'; // print the values in columns
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

This is just an example of how to do it. You can implement as you want.

Answer (score 0):

forloop the array up to half size of array and push elements in to a new array

```
for($i=0;$i<(sizeof($array)/2);$i++) {
    $newarray[]=$array[$i];
}
```