# In php How i divide a array by user input for make it to another some arrays

Tags: php

Suppose my array is:

```
$letters = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
```

and user input is:

$number = "4";

Now how i convert this array on look like that:

```
$array1 = array("a","b","c","d");

$array2 = array("e","f","g","h");

$array3 = array("i","j","k","l");
```

Comment: [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk)?

Comment: what have you done so far? show some effort on your part, some code you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i take an array, divide it by two and create two lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393028/how-can-i-take-an-array-divide-it-by-two-and-create-two-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://php.net/array_chunk

If you want to split the array in 4 then your code should look like this.

```
$output_array=array_chunk($letters, 4);
```

This will return you two dimensional array having chunks of array of 4 key,value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_chunk — Split an array into chunks:

Ex

```
array array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

So Use

```
array_chunk($letters,4,true)
```