# Split attribute groups by odd/even in two columns in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to split the big attribute table in two separate columns with dl list. Opencart version 2.2.0.0

The code now is (in /view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl):

```
<?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <div class="tab-pane tab-content <?php if ($is_active) { echo 'active'; $is_active = false; } ;?>" id="tab-specification">
      <dl>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
          <p><strong><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></strong></p>
          <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
          <dt><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></dt>
          <dd><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></dd>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </dl>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split array into 2 and loop trough them using foreach.

[How can i take an array, divide it by two and create two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393028/how-can-i-take-an-array-divide-it-by-two-and-create-two-lists)

```
<?php if ($attribute_groups) {
    $firsthalf = array_slice($attribute_groups, 0, $len / 2);
    $secondhalf = array_slice($attribute_groups, $len / 2);
?>
    <div class="tab-pane tab-content <?php if ($is_active) { echo 'active'; $is_active = false; } ;?>" id="tab-specification">
      <dl>
        <?php foreach ($firsthalf as $attribute_group) { ?>
          <p><strong><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></strong></p>
          <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
          <dt><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></dt>
          <dd><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></dd>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <?php foreach ($secondhalf as $attribute_group) { ?>
          <p><strong><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></strong></p>
          <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
          <dt><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></dt>
          <dd><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></dd>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </dl>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

There might be also css solution for that, but you tagged it with php so I guess this will work better for you.