# Array into chunks and results by chunks in a new line with php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

So as a title says:
I have an array

```
array(0=>"a"1=>"b"2=>"c"3=>"d"4=>"e"5=>"f")
```

What I want to do is loop through and chunk results and print them like this

`ab
cd
ef`

OR

`abc
def`

So far I got this:
I chunked array with array_chunk() like this

```
$chunks = array_chunk($my_array, 3);
```

So it gives me result like this:

```
Array(0 => array(0=>"a"1=>"b"2=>"c")1=>array(4=>"d"5=>"e"6=>"f"))
```

So I loop through

```
foreach($chunks as $key => $value){
   echo $value.'<br>';}
```

**Current output:**

`a
b
c
d
e
f`

**Desire output:**

`abc
def`

Any Ideas?

Also I'm on laravel just in case anyone knows a specific approach

Comment: `echo $value` with provided array will output word `Array`, show real code.

Comment: Is the array a collection?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/6c3be

Answer (score 9):

Since this is tagged with `laravel` I assume you want a laravel answer too(?).

[You can use the chunk function that comes with laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-chunk)

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);

$chunks = $collection->chunk(4);

$chunks->toArray();

// [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The chunks you created are array.

You can prints them when using:

```
$arr= array(0=>"a",1=>"b",2=>"c",3=>"d",4=>"e",5=>"f");
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3);
foreach($chunks as $key => $value)
    echo implode("",$value). "\n";
```

Output:

```
abc
def
```

Comment: @Davis did my post answer you?